# TailwindCSS doesn't work padding in VSCODE but it works in TailwindPlay

Tags: tailwind-css

I recently started to learn TailwindCSS a few hours ago and I wanted to create a navbar with using tailwindcss. I installed and set up everything, so I even tried to create a circle with tailwind and everything was working fine.

I wanted to create a navbar and gave some style.(background, etc...) was working fine.

Then, I wanted to add a  padding(p-(value) in tailwindcss)
But it didnt worked. I just checked if there's problem with code or not using TailwindPlay(tailwind css emulator) so, the code was working fine in there.

But in my VSCode, padding doesn't work. I do not have any idea why.

Here's my codes;
`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <!--Navbar-->
    <nav class="relative container mx-auto p-15">Hello</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

`

I'm looking forward to someone who can help me with that...
I'm the fresh guy and I do not want to give up after started to learn something new

I just checked if there's problem with code or not using TailwindPlay(tailwind css emulator) so, the code was working fine in there.

But in my VSCode, padding doesn't work. I do not have any idea why.

Comment: is p-15 the only value that doesn't work or all padding?

Comment: Thank you for your input. I've just tried to write this in the terminal npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./build/css/style.css --watch and it's just worked. But I don't think it's good to write this everytime when i want to add smth which is not exist in the tailwind

Answer (score 0):

Class **p-15** doesn't exist in tailwind. Only **p-14** and **p-16**. You can create your own padding **p-15** using ***tailwind.config.js***
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/padding#customizing-your-theme

Also, I recommend you use **Tailwind CSS IntelliSense** plugin in VSCode

````
  theme: {
    extend: {
      padding: {
        '15': '3.75rem', // 60px
      }
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'm already using Tailwind CSS IntelliSense extension. I've just tried to write this in the terminal npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./build/css/style.css --watch and it's just worked. But I don't think it's good to write this everytime when i want to add smth which is not exist in the tailwind

Comment: Easy configuration is provided in Tailwind. It is great because you can configure your project as your designer needs. Just do the configuration as described in the documentation.